# searching in list getting true infinitely in prolog

Tags: list, search, prolog

I tried to code a Prolog program that takes 2 value and calculates if the pair is valid or not. If pairs are in different lists, then pairs will be valid and they can make match. If two team in same list(group) then they can't make match which means false.

when i started the program it doesn't show anything. I thought there would be infinite searching or looping. Then tried that simple code

```
GroupB=[china,usa,chile,italy].

member(X,[X|_]).
member(X,[_|T]):-
   member(X,T).

match(X):-
   member(X,GroupB).
```

In that code i saw that program always gives me true. I typed; to SWI-Prolog it gave me another true, i typed ; again another true then i realized that the problem should be in that searching part. Thanks for all interests from now. All suggestions are welcome.

edit:
I edited the code like that to try a different style

```
GroupA([germany,brazil,turkey,korea]).
GroupB([china,usa,chile,italy]).

member(X,[X|_]).
member(X,[_|T]):-
   member(X,T).

memberence(X):-
   GroupA(L).
   GroupB(M).
   member(X,L).
   member(X,M).

collision(X,Y):-
   GroupA(L),
   member(X,L),
   member(Y,L).
   GroupB(L),
   member(X,L),
   member(Y,L).

match(X,Y) :-
   GroupA(L),
   memberence(X),
   memberence(Y),
   \+collision(X,Y).
```

now i got:
ERROR: Undefined procedure: match/2
ERROR:     However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         catch/3

although there is a match(X,Y) procedure why it gives me undefined match/2 error.

```
GroupA=[germany,brazil,turkey,korea].
GroupB=[china,usa,chile,italy].

member(X,[X|_]).
member(X,[_|T]):-
   member(X,T).

memberence(X):-
   member(X,GroupA).
   member(X,GroupB).

collision(X,Y):-
   member(X,GroupA),
   member(Y,GroupA).
   member(X,GroupB),
   member(Y,GroupB).

match(X,Y) :-
   memberence(X),
   memberence(Y),
   \+collision(X,Y).
```

Comment: Write `groupA(` etc in place of `GroupA(` Also, there are many `.` where `,` should be!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a)

You have a dot that must be comma in:

```
collision(X,Y):-
   member(X,GroupA),member(Y,GroupA).
   member(X,GroupB),member(Y,GroupB).
```

b)

Better you do not redefine "member", it is standard.

c)

If I change dot by comma in:

```
collision(X,Y):-
  GroupA(L),member(X,L),member(Y,L),
  GroupB(L),member(X,L),member(Y,L).
```

this statement will fail always because there are no list "L" common to GroupA and GroupB.

d)

If we take what seems the original request "takes 2 value and calculates if the pair is valid or not. If pairs are in different lists, then pairs will be valid and they can make match. If two team in same list(group) then they can't make match which means false."

the solution seems obvious:

```
match(X,Y) :- groupA(A), member(X,A), groupB(B), member(Y,B).
match(Y,X) :- groupA(A), member(X,A), groupB(B), member(Y,B).
```

Comment: a) if i make first dot to comma like 

       `member(X,GroupA),member(Y,GroupA),`

        `member(X,GroupB),member(Y,GroupB).`

then it will be true ONLY X in groupa and groupb and Y is in groupA and groupB  which is not possible. There are two collisions for me if they both in groupa OR if they both in groupb if one of them happens means there is collisions so it must be dot not comma.

c) i didnt understand the point in c) if you change dot by comma and it fails then dont change it. i will change the name of atom for GropB() check and try again. but it will be dot not comma.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 big problems.

- First, you seem to use `.` and `,` interchangeably.
- Second, you fail to understand Prolog's scoping rules. Anything that isn't asserted into the prolog database is scoped to the immediate statement or the clause of the predicate of which is a part. If you want somebody to know about it, it either has to be a part of the prolog database or passed as an argument. Thus, when you say something like

  GroupB = [china,usa,chile,italy].

The variable `GroupB` Is *unified* with the list `[china,usa,chile,italy]`. At which point, the assertion succeeds, and both the newly-bound variable and the list with which it was unified ** go out of scope** and cease to exist. Then, when you attempt to reference it later on:

```
GroupB=[china,usa,chile,italy].
.
.
.
match(X) :- member(X,GroupB).
```

The variable `GroupB` is *unbound*. Your implementation of `member/2`,

```
GroupB=[china,usa,chile, 

member(X,[X|_]) .
member(X,[_|T]) :- member(X,T) .
```

is more than willing to act in a *generative* manner when given an *unbound* variable as its 2nd argument, generating lists of variable, successively (and infinitely) longer on backtracking.